# EhCache 3.9 -- Get All Cache Entries (working in EhCache 2.10)

Tags: java, spring-boot, ehcache-3, cachemanager

The following code to fetch all caches is working in 2.10 (net.sf.ehcache.*)

```
public Map<CacheRegion, Map<Object, Element>> getCache() {
    Map<CacheRegion, Map<Object, Element>> cachedData = new HashMap<CacheRegion, Map<Object, Element>>();

    for (CacheRegion cacheRegion : CacheRegion.values()) {
        Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache(cacheRegion.getRegionName());
        Ehcache ehCache = ((EhCacheCache) cache).getNativeCache();
        Map<Object, Element> cacheMap = ehCache.getAll(ehCache.getKeys());
        cachedData.put(cacheRegion, cacheMap);
    }

    return cachedData;
}

// CacheRegion is an enum with cache keys
```

How can I achieve the same in EhCache 3.9 (org.ehcache.*)? I have at least 2 different types of entities being cached. I tried looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50389398/4669619 but that did not work for me. So far, I have replaced `Element` with `Object`.

```
public Map<CacheRegion, Map<Object, Object>> getCache() {
    Map<CacheRegion, Map<Object, Object>> cachedData = new HashMap<CacheRegion, Map<Object, Object>>();

    for (CacheRegion cacheRegion : CacheRegion.values()) {
        Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache(cacheRegion.getRegionName());
        ...
    }
}
```

- `Element` in 2.x example can work for any/all entity. It's not available in 3.x, so I've tried to use `Object` instead
- `Ehcache` is also not available in 3.x, so I can't store the result of `((EhCacheCache) cache).getNativeCache();` in that
- `Ehcache` not being available in 3.x means `getAll` functionality is not available

Any suggestions/ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this post [EHCache 3.5 Get All Cache Keys / Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368760/ehcache-3-5-get-all-cache-keys-entries) this is not a simple API call in Ehcache 3.

But you can get all keys like this.

```
StreamSupport.stream(cacheManager.getCache(cacheName).spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 CacheManager.ALL_CACHE_MANAGERS.stream()
    .forEach(cacheManager -> Arrays.stream(cacheManager.getCacheNames()).forEach(s -> log.info("Cache {} -> {}", s, cacheManager.getCache(s))));
```